# How can we classify and differentiate sources of information for humans?

Tags: knowledge, philosophy-of-history, information

I was always taught in elementary about the primary, secondary, and tertiary sources of information. However, as I ponder about it I thought in a scenario of the game "pass the message" where ten kids pass the message to the end of the line, the idea of primary, secondary, and tertiary source of information is insufficient, as quartic, quantic, sextic, and so on would be possible, and it wouldn't matter the medium the sender of the information uses.

So my question is, what sources of information exist that affects the growth and learning of a sample human being? Is it the Reality? The humans it was surrounded? Is it the book? Is it the internet? How can we classify and differentiate these things? How does Education maximize these resources and human resources for the information an individual should get? Why is symbolism such a great tool, and who can use this tool and why was this possible?

Sorry for the picture, but I tried a little just to arrange my thoughts, but the only thing I got was confusion.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is practically important through how many hands the information has passed because of trustworthiness and accumulation of errors, but philosophically, getting it through one or ten other people makes little difference. For a more philosophically salient distinction see [SEP, Knowledge by Acquaintance vs. Knowledge by Description](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-acquaindescrip/).

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: The notion of grading the reliability of sources of information, as far as I know, is philosophically speaking, primarily studied by the [philosophy of history (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/history/) and the [philosophy of law (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lawphil-nature/) since the question of what constitutes adequate [evidence (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evidence/) is very important to both disciplines. This might be in contrast to mathematics where proof inheres more to the argument than the source. I haven't seen much expertise of either on PhilSE.

Comment: It does occur to me that if you are talking about sources of KNOWLEDGE, then you are very much in the territory of [epistemology (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology/), like Robert Audi's claim that all knowledge comes from perception, memory, consciousness, reason, and testimony. But epistemology is a very broad field, and your question is very broad and needs to be narrowed down. Otherwise, it's fair to say that every discipline that speaks to a field of knowledge has its own standards